# Address of templated inline constexpr variable is not treated as constant expression by gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, constexpr, compiler-bug

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline constexpr int a = 1;

static_assert(&a<void>, "");
```

This [does not compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-TBQ-y) on gcc 9.2, but compiles on both clang and msvc.

Gcc complains that the expression used for `static_assert` is not constant expression.

The code compiles after removing template, removing inline, or removing address-of operator.

Is this a gcc bug?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug.

Comment: *"removing address-of"*. That really changes the meaning of the code.

Comment: It is accepted by the latest GCC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xsMrM7soq